# JavaScript | How can I reference multiple instances of specific data in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**SUMMARY:** I am creating a small, recreational project where the user enters their drink preferences and the website returns drinks that correspond to the preferences. The drinks are stored in objects within an array.

**EXPECTED:** I have 6 drinks (objects) within an array named `drinks2020[]`. Each object within the array follows the same convention - containing a name, type, base, ingredients, and method. For example:

```
let drinks2020 = [
house_punch = {
    "name": "House Punch",
    "type": "punch",
    "base": "bourbon",
    "ingredients": "1oz Bourbon, 1oz Orange Juice, 0.25oz Lemon Juice, 0.50oz Cinnamon-Vanilla, 0.25oz Allspice.",
    "method": "Shake and strain into glass mug with orange ice cube."
    }
];
```

I am starting small with the user's preferences, working with the `base`. If the user inputs 'Bourbon', the app should return all drinks with `"base": "bourbon"`.

**PROBLEM:** This may be more of a conceptual problem, but I've found that I can't create an if-statement using the `"base"` value of *each* object value without explicitly referencing a value in the array. My intention looks something like this:

```
if (base === 'bourbon') {
   console.log(drinks2020[].base);
}
```

This returns an error as `[]` is unexpected. Of course, I can call `drinks2020[0].base` and the app will return `bourbon`. Yet, I can't call `drinks2020[0,1,2,3].base` (etc).

**CONSIDERATIONS:** If I remove the name values, and create an array of objects without object literals, I think I would be able to retrieve the data using `drinks2020.base`. However I feel it will be easier as I expand the app to have another layer of naming conventions.

**QUESTION:** What are some resources I can look into about array/object hierarchy, and are there any javaScript methods that could help me with referencing the data of all objects in an array?

**EDIT:** This is a solution that worked for me:

```
let spirit = prompt("What spirit do you prefer?");
for (let i = 0; i < drinks2020.length; i++ ) {
    if (drinks2020[i].base == spirit) {
        returnArr.push(drinks2020[i].name);
        let showDrinksAsString = returnArr.join(', ');
        document.getElementById('drink_name').innerHTML = showDrinksAsString;
    }
}
```

Comment: for(i in array){
  if(arrayi[i].base=="bourbon"){
     ` do something`
  }.
}        you can do this

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter function.

const drinks = drinks2020.filter( drink => drink.base === 'bourbon' );

Refer MDN docs on filter [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) .

Comment: I added an edit to the question, showing what I ended up using which worked correctly. Given that I will be adding more preferences (taste, citrus, flavor, etc.) - which method do you think would be more efficient?